# MySQL Wildcard Match Substring for Two Fields

Tags: mysql, email, email-validation

here's what I'd like do to:

I have a MYSQL database that has several fields - the fields I'm referring to are `contact_email` and `site_url` in a table called `url_links`

What I'm looking for is a simple 'update' query that will set a binary flag if there's a match.

in pseudo-code:

> Update url_links SET domainMatch=1 where { substring of contact_email
>   after @ } = { substring of site_url - could be http://  https:// 
>   https://www  or any url - i.e. just the domain name }

so if email is something like  `mywebsiteisgreat@gmail.com` and domain is `http://www.mywebsiteisgreat.com` it will not match

but if the email is `jim@mywebsiteisgreat.com` it would set the domainMatch field to 1 - the domains match.

Thanks!

Comment: thank you Martin for improving my question. While we're on the subject - what's the best practice here to explain WHY a solution works.  I'm still trying to wrap my mind around the amazing things you can do with MySQL. I could do these same things in PHP with loops but its soooo much cooler to do it directly in MYSQL. We'll all learn more if we perhaps also list references to functions and links to those to help readers understand why things are the way they are. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE url_links
SET domainMatch = 1
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(contact_email,'@', -1)
LIKE CONCAT('%', SUBSTRING_INDEX(site_url,'.', -2), '%');
```

( I updated this with the database actual field names so we can test it easier )

Comment: That didn't work right it didn't find the right emails in the database.  That's because the database contains mostly URLS with 'http://' and 'https://' - it only found those that were bad records i.e. missing the http://   so an updated script would need to strip away the http://  https://  and http://www. and https://www or any other combination perhaps http://m.  

Perhaps the way to do this would be to simply only look for a substring on the URL field that is AFTER the FIRST DOT (.) that would cover most URLS

Comment: I worked on this a little just now. See if SUBSTRING_INDEX() does the trick

Comment: Thanks for keeping with it - that didn't do much more - its still only 'finding' records that are missing http:// - i.e. the errors in the database. :)  I'm leaning towards perhaps doing 2 queries - a)  a query to extract the domain name into its own field let's call it 'domain' and then b) your query which works great as long as the domain name itself is isolated. What do you think? Is it even possible to do with 1 query?